# How do I print an image in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have an iOS SwiftUI app that downloads an image in a view. How can I send it to a printer when the user taps on the image?

```
struct imageView: View {

   var body: some View {
      let image = viewModel.download()

      Image(image).onTapGesture {
         ... what do I do here? ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should have to trigger the share link or UIPrintInteractionController.BTW the body is for UI, You shouldn’t trigger downloads with redraws of a body. Some basic SwiftUI tutorials will be very helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what kind of printer you're using so I'm assuming it supports Bluetooth. In this circumstance, you can try `ShareLink` on iOS 16 or above. However, it represents a kind of button and it needs an action to show up a share sheet. So, if you need a trigger here, you may consider wrapping `UIActivityViewController` from UIKit.

```swift
struct ActivityController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var items: [Any]

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityController>) -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items,
                                                  applicationActivities: [])
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController,
                                context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityController>) { }
}
```

As @loremipsum said, the body of a View is presenting UI only, so you need to move the download function to the viewModel, and assign the image to a `@Published` property. Whenever it changes, it will automatically notice the view to render.

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    
    func download() async {
        image = ...
    }
}
```

Then on the SwiftUI file:

```swift
@StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
@State private var presentShare = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(viewModel.image != nil ? "Loaded" : "Loading")
        if let image = viewModel.image {
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .onTapGesture {
                    presentShare = true
                }
        }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $presentShare, content: {
        ActivityController(items: [viewModel.image])
    })
    .onAppear {
        Task {
            try? await viewModel.download()
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]